# A lot of lag with nVidia GeForce 820M 2GB

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

Have a laptop with an NVIDIA GEFORCE 820M 2GB with i5-5200U and 4GB RAM, however on a game where the minimum requirements are GeForce 210 and 1GB RAM I cant even run it on lowest setting possible. It tell me I have a CPU lag of 50 seconds and its running at 6FPS!

I'm worried that its not running on my NVIDIA and using the Intel HD Graphics instead and that's why I have this problem (I'm not very good with computers so this is probably soooo wrong).
How do I make sure that the game is running on the NVIDIA

Comment: Serious question, did you plug your monitor into the video card instead of the motherboard's video port? What exact version of the nvidia driver do you have installed? Which game is this?

Comment: If its a 820M, its a laptop. So... probably not plugged into the wrong port.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting inside the Nvidia control pannel that says something to the effect of "default GPU". You'll find it.

You may find that it is by default set to use best device. Sometimes I find that it's very, very bad at using the right device. For me, Minecraft would always use the iGPU, which was terrible. Switch it to use your Nvidia GPU at all times. (I apologize for the ambiguity of the setting name. I don't my computer at the moment. Feel free to comment the actual name.)